# Is Avast 8 GUI built in flash or other component?

Tags: user-interface, antivirus

Just out of curiosity, I wonder if Avast uses flash on your GUI, or other component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be uncommon to build a desktop application in Flash. Typically it's C++/.NET and the WinAPI.

Comment: yes, but withit's possible.